# Laravel session for Custom Authentication

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using one laravel 5.7 authentication with custom check and session.
I have 5 type of user types

> Session::put('user_type',  $user_type);
>         Session::put('user_id',  $user_id);

When I tried to check session data in constructor I am facing one issue,Please hele me to solve this,

> ErrorException (E_NOTICE) Trying to get property 'headers' of
>   non-object

```
 public function __construct()
    {              
        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        $utype=Session::get('user_type');
        if($utype != 'ProjectAdmin'){
            return redirect()->route('login');
        }else{
            $this->objShareContract = shareContract::getShareContract(TRUE);
        }
    });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Middleware must return a Response. You are not returning a Response from this custom Closure based middleware. You have 2 logical paths and only one of them is returning a Response of some sort.

There are other middleware before this one that are expecting a Response to come back through the pipeline. That is what the `return $next($request);` is about.

Comment: okay thanks.if($utype != 'ProjectAdmin'){
            return redirect()->route('login');
        }
        $this->objShareContract = shareContract::getShareContract(TRUE);
        return $next($request); I changed like these now working,Thanks..